# two PIRs problem

Tags: gpio, python, camera, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

i am building a security system which consists of two PIRs (GPIO 17 & 18) relay GPIO 24 , video will be emailed and will receive a text message when motion is detected . the camera can see both PIRs locations . when PIR 1 or PIR 2 is activated separately the script is working perfectly ( i am receiving an email and text message and relay is working ) , however when both PIRs are activated together the script wont work it get stuck somehow  . the thing is i need to record a 5 seconds video if any of the PIRs is activated separately or both at the same time .  your support is needed !

thank you in advance

see below the script :

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio  
import picamera       
import time   
import os  
import email   
import sys

import smtplib   
from datetime import datetime  
from picamera import PiCamera  
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart  
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText   
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase  
from email import encoders   
from twilio.rest import Client   

 relay=24   
 pir1=18   
 pir2=17   

 HIGH=1   
 LOW=0   

gpio.setwarnings(False)      
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)     
gpio.setup(relay, gpio.OUT)                 
gpio.setup(pir1, gpio.IN)           
gpio.setup(pir2, gpio.IN)           

def start_recording_video():      
    video_name = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S")       
    camera.start_recording(video_name + h264_video)      
    time.sleep(5)      
    camera.stop_recording()      

os.system("MP4Box -add " + video_name + h264_video + " " + video_name + 
mp4_video) 

os.system("rm " + video_name + h264_video) 
footage = video_name + mp4_video

f_time = datetime.now().strftime("%A %B %d %Y @ %H:%M:%S")
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["Subject"] = f_time
msg["From"] = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
msg["To"] = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
text = MIMEText(" Motion Detected ")
msg.attach(text)

part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(footage, "rb").read())
email.encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= %s" % 
os.path.basename(footage))
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
server.starttls()
server.login("xxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxx")
server.sendmail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx@gmail.com", msg.as_string())
server.quit()

os.system("rm " + footage) 


def sending_a_text_message_1():     
    account_sid = 'xxxxxxxxx'    
    auth_token = 'xxxxxxxx'     
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)     
    message = client.messages \     
        .create(      
            body='Intruder Pir_1',    
            from_='+xxxxxx',   
            to='+xxxxxx'     
         )      

print(message.sid)     

def sending_a_text_message_2():      
    account_sid = 'xxxxxxx'      
    auth_token = 'xxxxxxxxx'       
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)     
    message = client.messages \  .create(     
             body='Intruder Pir_2',    
             from_='+xxxxx',      
             to='+xxxxxx'
         )    
print(message.sid)     

 gpio.output(relay , 0)    

 camera = PiCamera()
 camera.rotation = 180 
 h264_video = ".h264" 
 mp4_video = ".mp4"

while 1:            
   if gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==0 :      
       print " PIR1 Motion detected!"      
       gpio.output(relay, HIGH)     
       start_recording_video()     
       sending_a_text_message_1()     
       while(gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==0):    
           time.sleep(1)       

elif gpio.input(pir1)==0 and gpio.input(pir2)==1 :      
    print " PIR2 Motion detected!"     
    gpio.output(relay, HIGH)     
    start_recording_video()     
    sending_a_text_message_2()     
    while(gpio.input(pir1)==0 and gpio.input(pir2)==1):      
        time.sleep(1)      

elif gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==1 :      
    print " PIR1 & PIR2 Motion detected!"     
    gpio.output(relay, HIGH)     
    start_recording_video()          
    while(gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==1):      
        time.sleep(1)
else:                   
    gpio.output(relay, LOW)      
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Please edit your post so all code is in a code block. If your using Thonny on the Pi, select all code, press tab to indent all code, then paste into your post.

Comment: why do you have two functions for sending text messages?

Comment: separate the detection phase and the action phase (record,send)  ...... only set flags when motion is detected ....... after the detection phase, run actions, depending on the state of the flags

Comment: @jsotola hello , the body of each message is different , just to know from where the detection is coming whether PIR1 or PIR 2

Comment: @jsotola thanks for your valuable reply , to be honest i am very new with programming , would you mind giving me a script as an example ?

Comment: @rohtua's answer is the way I'd go, but the indenting in your code sample looks broken - you may have a mix of tab & spaces - can you use PasteBin or similar so we can see it how you see it - it should point the way for rohtua's fix to be implemented.

Comment: i ran the script on Thonny  , i  fixed all the debugs , but still when When PIR1 detects movement , the relay will go on , then the email takes some time ( like 1 min or more ) to be uploaded and sent , once the email is uploaded i receive a text message and then the relay will be off . If During this process PIR2 is activated , i will not still receive a message and email  but the PIR2 wont work  ,after that I will have to press control C (no errors at all will be printed on the screen ) So

Comment: both PIR are working perfectly if they are detected seperatly . maybe i shoud try to separate the detection phase and the action phase (record,send) ...... only set flags when motion is detected ....... after the detection phase, run actions, depending on the state of the flags as @jsotola 's advice or i should keep one of the PIRs sleeping until i receive a message . any idea how to do that ? or any idea how to make a script to separate the detection phase from the action phase ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you not need a third if section?? You've got if `if gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==0 :` then `elif gpio.input(pir1)==0 and gpio.input(pir2)==1 :` but nothing for when when both inputs = 1 so nothing will happen because you don't have a if statement that covers that contingency.  I think you need a third elif statement that covers `elif gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==1 :`

Comment: i actually tried this but didnt work  :                                                                           
elif gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==1 :      
    print " PIR1 and PRI2 Motion detected!"     
    gpio.output(relay, HIGH)     
    start_recording_video()       
    while(gpio.input(pir1)==1 and gpio.input(pir2)==1):      
        time.sleep(1)

Comment: Hmmmm. Not too sure then to be honest. When you say it doesn't work is it presenting any specific error or behaviour? Just on a bit of a tangent have you tried combining your current if statements into one so elif gpio.input(pir1)==1 or gpio.input(pir2)==1 : and then having your second if as the and.

Comment: it didnt show any error , it just freeze

Comment: Have you ran it in a python IDLE you should see some debug info if you run the script in there. Do you need to specify pir2 off or vice versa? Would it not work the same way if it was while 1: if gpio.input(pir1)==1 : print " PIR1 Motion detected!" gpio.output(relay, HIGH) start_recording_video() sending_a_text_message_1() while(gpio.input(pir1)==1: time.sleep(1) elif gpio.input(pir1) : print " PIR2 Motion detected!" gpio.output(relay, HIGH) start_recording_video() sending_a_text_message_2() while(gpio.input(pir1)==0): time.sleep(1) else: gpio.output(relay, LOW) time.sleep(0.01)

Comment: i didnt ran it in a python IDLE .. yes i have to specify ... it would work using the script you have given = if PIR1 is activated i will receive a message and email and if PIR1 not activated i will receive an email and text message without PIR2 sensor being activated also . if PIR2 is activated or not i will not receive anything ( no message and no email ) ... you got my point ?

Comment: If you want something to happen when *either* PIR1 *or* PIR2 are triggered you can simplify your code to just check for that: `if gpio.input( pir1 ) == 1 or gpio.input( pir2 ) == 1 :`. Any other state is a "don't care".